# A question about the representation theory of finite dimensional algebra

Tags: representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra, $M$ be a finite dimensional module of $A$.The socle of $M$, $\mathrm{soc}(M)$, is the maximal semisimple submodule of M. The top of $M$ is $\mathrm{top}(M)=M/\mathrm{rad}(M)$. $D$ is the standard $k$-linear duality, that is $D(M)= \mathrm{Hom}_k(M,k)$. I want to know if there is any relation between socle and top ? If $D(\mathrm{soc}M)=\mathrm{top}(D(M))$ or something else? Thank you.

This question was asked also [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_anyone_help_with_my_question_about_the_representation_theory_of_finite_dimensional_algebra?_tpcectx=profile_highlights) [accessed Nov 28, 2015].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question: No in general, unless you start by fixing a class of modules.  e.g. if $M$ is semi-simple, then clearly $\mathrm{soc}(M)=\mathrm{top}(M)$.

The second question: Yes.  To see this, use short exact sequence $0\to \mathrm{rad}(Ae_i) \to Ae_i \to S_i \to 0$, where $e_i$ is a primitive idempotent and $S_i$ is the corresponding simple module.  This gets sent to the short exact sequence $0\to S_i^{op} \to D(Ae_i) \to C \to 0$ where the starting terms describe the inclusion of a simple module into its the injective hull.  So this is true for all projectives.

Then consider the canonical projection $M \to \mathrm{top}(M)$ which can be extended to $P_M\to \mathrm{top}(M)$ with $P_M$ being the projective cover of $M$, which gives you commutative diagram
$$
\begin{array}[ccl]
\ P_M \to  & M \to & 0\\
|| & \downarrow & \\
P_M \to & \mathrm{top}M \to & 0
\end{array}
$$
Then apply $D$.